# Android Studio Marshmallow Issue (Activity class does not exist)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I started a project with android studio with lowest Android version 6.0.
I made a bit of worked and then wanted to try it on my device.
When I started to run it showed me this error:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.------.------/.Test }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.-----.------/com.example.-----.-----.Test} does not exist.
```

Then I tried to run another project on the same device and I got the same error.

I also tried the other project on another device which is running android 5.1.1 and it work perfectly.

After that I thought that could have come from my code, which might not be compatible with Marshmallow so what I did is:
Create a brand new project with minimum Version 6.0, set a blank activity and without touching anything run on my phone, and I got the same issue.

I'm using:
Motorola Moto X 2014 with CM13,
Android Studio 1.4.1,
Galaxy S3 as device running 5.1.1,
and ubuntu 15.10

I've already tried a lot of fixes but none of them worked.
I hope you could help me to find a fix to that,
Thanks for your help :)

[EDIT]
Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.------.------" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[EDIT] MainActivity class + Gradle files

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.-----.--------;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig
    {
        applicationId "com.example.------.-----------"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Gradle (Project: --------)

```
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects
{
    repositories
    {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete)
{
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Do you use the build tools 1.5.0-beta? In my case this resulted compiling bugs. Using 1.3.0 fixed it.

Comment: I'm already using build tool 1.3.0 :/

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: I would try to use something different than com.example. I do not expect that this changes anything but give it a try.

Comment: I've created a new project with a different package name but I still get the same error :/

Comment: Could you add your grade files and your MainActivity class? Could help.

Comment: Not sure why it is failing to load some 'Test' activity. Can you post the full package names (or modify your program such that you can show the package names)? Along with that, can you display your Android view w/ all files (e.g. app/java/your.package.name should show files & more packages).

Comment: I'll do that when I'll be on my computer, for the Test Class, I have created one named like that to try but remains the same as MainActivity, also for gradle and MainActivity I didn't even change them it doesn't work even with the auto generated code, I think it might come from Android studio settings :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try that with your **Instant Run** feature off. 
This will work. **Instant Run is a feature to hot swap only the changed files in the machine for the build currently available in session.**